# ndarray - Trying to use impl AddAssign<ArrayBase> for ArrayBase causes compiler error

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, traits

I am using ndarray crate (version `0.13.1`) for vector and matrix operations and I've encountered an error for which I'd like to find an explanation (and a solution).

Take note of this code:

```
use ndarray as nd;
fn main() {
    let mut matrix: nd::Array2<f64> = nd::Array::zeros((3, 4));
    let additional: nd::Array2<f64> = nd::Array::ones((3, 4));
    matrix += additional; // <- Compiler error
}
```

I'd assume this code compiles and runs correctly, as `AddAssign<ndarray::ArrayBase` is implemented for `ndarray::ArrayBase` ([see documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-AddAssign%3C%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS2%2C%20E%3E%3E)), and the shapes match. Right...?

No.
I get two compiler errors for the same (third) line (see at the bottom of the question).

My humble interpretation of these errors is that the compiler doesn't seem to notice the `AddAssign<BaseArray>` implementation for `BaseArray` - it take into account only the `AddAssign<B> where B: ScalarOperand` (which is documented as well, surely, right [here](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-AddAssign%3CA%3E)).

I wonder if my code doesn't match the `AddAssign<BaseArray>` implementation somehow, and if it does - what else could be the problem?
It also intrigues me that the compiler expects `f64` as the rhs of the `+=` operation - what can possibly cause it to completely ignore the fact that `BaseArray` is indeed expected at this position?

Any help would be much, much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

The errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64> as ndarray::data_traits::RawData>::Elem == ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
    --> src\main.rs:11:12
    |
11  |     matrix += additional;
    |            ^^ expected `f64`, found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase`
    |
    = note: expected type `f64`
            found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::AddAssign` for `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>: ndarray::impl_ops::ScalarOperand` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:11:12
    |
11  |     matrix += additional;
    |            ^^ the trait `ndarray::impl_ops::ScalarOperand` is not implemented for `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::AddAssign` for `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0271, E0277.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
```

Comment: So you're saying that there is an impl for `AddAssign<&'a ArrayBase<S2, E>>AddAssign<&'a ArrayBase<S2, E>>`... but you are trying to add by value, not a reference. Try: `matrix += &additional;`.

Comment: @PeterHall I knew it as something like that, I can't believe I couldn't notice it myself. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHall I now only wonder why can't the compiler catch this mistake - why does it expect `f64` and not `&ArrayBase<...>`? (I guess it relates to the order of trait implementation matching check rules or something...?)

Comment: It is possibly something you could submit an issue for. Good error/help messages are a high priority for the compiler team.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implementation of `AddAssign<ArrayBase>` for `ArrayBase` (type params ommitted for brevity). But *there is* [an implementation for `AddAssign<&ArrayBase>`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-AddAssign%3C%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS2%2C%20E%3E%3E).

Auto-deref rules sometimes make it feel like you can use references or values interchangeably, but this mechanism doesn't extend to trait implementations or type parameters, so you need to be more explicit here.

You can fix your code by passing by reference:

```
matrix += &additional;
```

The error message is correct, but leads you in the wrong direction by talking about the implementation for `AddAssign<f64>`. It could be worth [logging an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AA-diagnostics+) with this example, in case the compiler team can see a way to improve it.

Comment: How come there isn't there an implementation for an `AddAssign` that consumes the RHS? I don't see an obvious use case for that in particular, but I came to this question wondering the same thing but for adding two `ArrayBase`s, where you could want to steal one of them to avoid making a new one for the return value.